# Excel date extraction function returned #VALUE

Tags: excel, date

In an existing report, there was a function that extracts month and year from the date data using the function below:

```
=DATE(LEFT($L$5,4),MID($L$5,6,2),RIGHT($L$5,2))
```

The date is of format:

```
2020-11-01
```

I then want to introduce some new data to replace the old data. The data also has the same format as the old data, however, the date extraction function now returned `#VALUE!`. I tried to change the date format a few times but did not help. The old and new dates look of the same format, why did the function work for one but not for the other?

Comment: What was the actual date that gave the error?

Comment: @bugdrown One example is `1/12/2021`. I just typed the date and convert to date format. But for the old date, I just realised the data format is "general". Does that mean the date data was actually in text format?

Comment: If you enter `2021/12/01`, does that give an error?

Comment: No, it means that there's actually a number that Excel displays as a date by default. That won't work wit the date extractor. You'd  need the input cells formatted as text.

Comment: I see. I tried to simply change the data format from `date` to `text` but the date became a string of numeric data, such as `44531` from `1/12/2021`

Comment: The date extractor formula is expecting text. The `LEFT()`  `MID()`, and `RIGHT()` functions operate on text. `GENERAL` and `DATE` formats will display date type entries as dates but the behind the scenes data is a number (the number of days since 1/1/1900). Also, the extractor will only work with text in this format: 2022-01-01.

Comment: So in order to allow the function to work for my new data do I need to change the date data into number behind the scene? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241120/discussion-between-bugdrown-and-nilsinelabore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force date data to string format before use `left`, `right`, `mid` or other string function in excel could solve this problem. You can use `'` (single quote) before your date data to force it to string.

The image shows how it works.

[image]